# How to check if an output stream is std::cout in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, stream, cout

I'm implementing an output stream operator<< overload, and I need to check that the output stream parameter os is std::cout, and if not, throw std::runtime_error - how can I check it?

```
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Software &soft)
```

Comment: Just compare the addresses. But... why would you want that?

Comment: Why are you even overloading `operator<<` for this purpose?  Why don't you just write a function called something like `Print(const Software &soft)` that just outputs to `cout`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I question the kind of logic that would lead you to think you have to do this, but if you really want to...

```
if (&os != &std::cout) {
    throw std::runtime_error(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: The reason is that I have a C implementation which is only defined for standard output, and I'm creating a c++ wrapper for it.

Comment: It still feels like you should be taking a different approach.  Consuming code might call this overload with some other stream, and this will compile just fine, even though it will blow up later.  Generally if you have to enforce that some argument is a particular value, you're doing things wrong.  Let the compiler help you as much as possible.

Comment: You could always ignore the `os` parameter and print to `std::cout` anyway.

Comment: @rvalue That would be even worse.

Comment: @rise, if it works for std::cout, it should equally work for std::cerr or any other stream for that matter.  If anything, provide a static method which returns an instance of your class instantiated with std::cout.  Anything different is not respecting [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) architecture.

Comment: @cdhowie I don't think throwing a `std::runtime_error` is better; You're right, a different approach is needed.  I think @benjamin-lindley is probably closest with using a `Print()` function or method instead.

Comment: @rvalue Throwing is better than ignoring the parameter completely; at least the developer will know unambiguously that something is wrong.  Ignoring the parameter and writing to stdout anyway is a **very** bad thing to do, as it will likely lead the developer on a wild goose chase trying to figure out how they streamed into `std::cout` by accident when they really didn't.  Having said that, both solutions are suboptimal.

Comment: @rvalue To expand on my comment, the reason I really don't like the "write to stdout anyway" solution is because it violates the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  It's astonishing for a function to only accept one specific value for an argument, but it's even more astonishing for a function to *disregard an argument and do something I didn't ask it to do.*

Comment: @cdhowie As you say, both options are bad.  The signature of the operator can't be changed for this form of usage, nor can the contract be satisfied for arbitrary `ostream&`.  I'd still probably go with ignoring the parameter, but either way I'd mark the function with a `#warning` or `__attribute__((deprecated))` or something.